# calling SPARK SQL inside map function

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

In my code I am have a requirement where I need to call spark sql for each of the rows of a `dataset`.

Now, spark sql requires `SparkSession` inside map function, which is not possible to pass as a broadcast Variable.

So, is there anyway to call Spark SQL inside a **`map function`**?

I have checked online but I was not able to find any information related to same.

I am using Java as a Programming language for SPARK.

**SPARK VERSION  : 2.3.0**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you write your SQL-function that you want to execute? It will be much easier to propose you a solution you need.

Comment: @ruslangm I want to fire simple SELECT queries inside map function of SPARK.

Answer (score -1):

Map applies a function on every item of a `Dataset` and returns another `Dataset`. What you need here is to iterate on every item with a `org.apache.spark.api.java.function.ForeachFunction`. Then you can execute spark sql for each item.

Example:

```
data.foreach((ForeachFunction<Row>) row -> System.out.println(row));
```